# Writing an extremely simple linear program

Tags: formatting, amsmath

I am trying to create a linear program

Similar to:

[image]

However the code just wouldn't align f(x) with the constraints
[image]

Can anyone help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools}       

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]



\theoremstyle{plain}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, numberwithin=section]{thm}
\declaretheorem[name=Lemma, numberwithin=section]{lem}
\declaretheorem[name=Proposition, numberwithin=section]{prop}
\declaretheorem[name=Corollary, numberwithin=section]{cor}
\declaretheorem[name=Conjecture, numberwithin=section]{conj}
\declaretheorem[name=Claim, numberwithin=section]{claim}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        & \text{maximize}
        & f(x) \\
        & \text{subject to}
        &  x_1+x_2 = 8\\
        & & x_3 + x_4 = 2
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `alignat` to define a number of Right-Left alignments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  & \text{maximize}   & \quad & f(x)          \nonumber \\
  & \text{subject to} &       & x_1 + x_2 = 8 \\
  &                   &       & x_3 + x_4 = 2 \nonumber
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My triple PhD degree will never finish without you

Answer (score 0):

Each line of your aligned environment starts with &. Delete it and replace the remaining & on each line by &~.